# Getting lot of 'del' call on GCP Memorystore. But couldn't identify its source

Tags: caching, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I am getting a lot of 'del' call on GCP Memorystore approx at a rate of 6k/sec. But I am unable to identify the source that's making these 'del' calls.

I have tried accessing logs of the particular memory-store server but didn't get anything related with calls information.

I need to figure out who is making these 'del' calls on my memorystore.

Any suggestions......

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `monitor` command to list every command processed by Redis server. You need to use with `grep` to filter `DEL` commands from the whole stream. By default `grep` is case sensitive, `-i` is added for to filter both `DEL` and `del`.

```
redis-cli -h your.host.name monitor | grep -i del
```

it will print in following format. You may use ip address to identify who is deleting.

```
1588013292.976045 [0 127.0.0.1:44098] "del" "foo"
1588013294.875606 [0 127.0.0.1:44098] "DEL" "foo"
1588013298.285791 [0 127.0.0.1:44098] "dEl" "foo"
```

Using `monitor` is not going to be free, please check the [benchmark](https://redis.io/commands/monitor#cost-of-running-monitor) numbers.